# Homogeneous Equation of second degree in x and y.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the single equation of the two lines through the origin and perpendicular to the each lines represented by $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$

I tried the factorization of the given equation but it was fail..

Answer (score 1):

Given $ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 = 0$ is equation of two lines passing through origin. 
 Let the equation of lines be 
$y = m_1x$ and $y = m_2x$

Dividing the equation by 
$x^2$

$$b(\frac yx)^2 + 2h(\frac yx) + a = 0$$
We know 
$\frac yx$
 is the slope of the lines, say $m$
 Thus,
$$bm^2 + 2hm + a = 0$$

Its clearly a quadratic equation. Solving
$$m = \frac{-2h \pm \sqrt{4h^2 - 4ab}}{2b}$$
 or 
$$m = \frac{-h \pm \sqrt{h^2 - ab}}{b}$$
 Thus equation being
$$y = \frac{-h \pm \sqrt{h^2 - ab}}{b}x$$

Comment: for $y$ we must have $$y\ne 0$$ but what is in the other case?

Comment: I should've divided by $x$. Now if $x = 0$, then $x$ must be a factor of your equation i.e. $b=0$. You've $(ax+2hy)x = 0$. Thus either $x=0$ or $ax+2hy=0$. Put $b$ in the last equation, you'll divide by 0. Agreeing the fact that slope is not defined.